# Ubuntu 14.04 power manager not working

Tags: 14.04, power-management, indicator, gnome-power-manager

The power manager has suddenly stopped working on my Ubuntu. It shows plugged in and 100% charged all the time. I'm using dual-boot with Windows 7 and the Windows power management tool is working fine.
What might be the problem?